# Is this-> mandatory to access Base<T> identifiers from derived classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, name-lookup

This code compiles with MSVC 2015, but doesn't compile with Clang 5.0.0 (trunk 304874):

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
  T data;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
  auto getData() const
  {
    return data;
  }
};
```

Replacing `data` with **`this->data`** in `Derived::getdata()` makes Clang happy.

Which compiler is correct according to the C++ standard?

Must `this->` be used in template code to access an identifier of a base class?

Comment: msvc is wrong, obviously. `data` is a dependent name.

Comment: clang is correct, msvc is wrong.

Comment: MSVC is broken with regards to the two-phase-lookup rules, which include dependent names.

Comment: MSVC 2017 with the [`/permissive-`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) switch emits the error "C2065: 'data': undeclared identifier" for this code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Clang is correct.

[$17.6.2/3 Dependent names [temp.dep]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#3)

> In the definition of a class or class template, the scope of a dependent base class is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

For `return data;`, `data` is *unqualified*, then unqualified name lookup will be employed. This means the name in the base class `Base<T>` (which is a dependent base class because it depends on the template parameter `T`) shouldn't be found; i.e. the non-dependent names are not looked up in dependent base classes.

`this->data` or `Base<T>::data` makes it *qualified*. This means the name will be looked up at the time of instantiation, and at that time the exact base specialization that must be explored will be known.

Comment: `this->data` is not a qualified name.

Comment: Still wrong. "qualified name" and "dependent name" are not interchangeable. In fact, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @T.C. I'm confused; so I can't say `name` is non-dependent name or `this->data` is dependent name ? Then what should be the correct description for these names? Or I can only say they're `qualified` or `unqualified`? (but not `qualified name` etc?) Please tell me if I'm wrong at the basic of the answer, or is it a term issue?

Comment: The basics is correct, it's the terminology. "dependent name" has a very narrow and specific definition in the standard (it refers, roughly, to function names subject to ADL in the instantiation context). Here, the point is the other two forms bypass the rule you cited because neither uses unqualified lookup. `this->data` uses class member access lookup, and `Base<T>::data` uses qualified lookup.

Comment: @T.C.: The modern (standard) terminology is that `data` in `this->data` **is** a dependent ([temp.dep.type]/5) (member-)qualified ([basic.lookup.qual.general]/2) name.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is. Basically `data` depends on `T`.

There is a mechanism called two-phase lookup. Non-(template)dependent names are resolved immediately - at the point of *definition*. Your `data` does not exist yet, because `Base<T>` does not exist yet, as it was not *instantiated*. Thus, it complains that `data` is not found.

You need to hint compiler that `data` depends on the template, and the name lookup should be performed in the second phase, after template parameters are substituted, i.e. template class was instantiated. This can be done by using `this` or providing template dependent scope.

So, either `this->f()` or `Base<T>::f()` will work.