# Member accessibility when both Base and Derived are template instantiations?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, member-access

I'm puzzled by a compiler error regarding the visibility of an inherited member variable.  I reduced it to this minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Base {
    protected:
        T m_value = T{};
};

template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T> {
    public:
        void Foo() { std::cout << m_value; };
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    d.Foo();
}
```

MSVC reports:

```
Source.cpp(10,35): error C2065: 'm_value': undeclared identifier
Source.cpp(10,35): error C3861: 'm_value': identifier not found
```

I'm surprised:  `Derived<T>` should inherit `m_value` from  `Base<T>` and it should be accessible because it's protected.

I tried reducing the problem further:  Replacing `Base<T>` with a non-templated class and declaring its `m_value` as int [works](https://godbolt.org/z/3cczPj).  Keeping `Base<T>` as a template class and making `Derived` a non-templated class (that derives from `Base<int>`), [also works](https://godbolt.org/z/4jx75Y).  The problem is only when both are templates.

I found other StackOverflow questions with similar titles, but none of them were exactly this issue.  The problems in those usually involved shadowing or syntax errors.

I tried Compiler Explorer (godbolt.org) to see whether Clang and gcc agreed with MSVC.  [Clang 10](https://godbolt.org/z/b6aKa3) also reports the error, as does [gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps8W6z).  Oddly, the [MSVC 19.24](https://godbolt.org/z/ahhcaf) on Compiler Explorer happily compiles the code *without* errors.  My local MSVC is more recent:  19.26.  So the consensus of the current versions of the major C++ compilers is that the code is wrong.

Can someone explain why a protected member variable of a base class is not visible to the derived class when both the base and derived classes are template instantiations?

Comment: didnt find a duplciate, but I think it is this: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416954/is-this-mandatory-to-access-baset-identifiers-from-derived-classes?rq=1)

Comment: @chris:  Thanks!  I hadn't found that question in my search, perhaps because the title describes the solution rather than the problem.  The second answer there does a pretty good job of explaining why.